# How do I turn this simple elixir echo server, to a simple webserver?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to set up an echo server for elixir, that takes in simple HTML for the sake of simplicity, and just display it. What do I have to do in the server to make it do so?

I've tried to look at how others do their minimal build for a working server in Elixir, such as https://www.jungledisk.com/blog/2018/03/19/tutorial-a-simple-http-server-in-elixir/, seemed promising but I still have yet to know how to implement it in this.

An EchoServer that was provided

```
defmodule EchoServer do
  require Logger

  def accept(port) do
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(port,
      [:binary, packet: :line, active: false, reuseaddr: true])
    Logger.info "Accepting connections on port #{port}"
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp loop_acceptor(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    Task.start_link(fn -> serve(client) end)
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp serve(socket) do
    socket |> read_line() |> write_line(socket)
    :ok = :gen_tcp.close(socket)
  end

  defp read_line(socket) do
    {:ok, data} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
    data
  end

  defp write_line(line, socket) do
    :gen_tcp.send(socket, line)
  end

  def main(args \\ []) do
    accept(9999)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get some things straight.  A server can return some html, but it is a browser that displays the html.  For instance, if you type an address into a browser's address bar, that causes the browser to send a request to the server, and the server sends back a response--containing some html in the body of the response--which the browser parsers out of the response and interprets as colored text, pictures, etc., which is known as ***rendering the html***.

Note that html is just text that is formatted a certain way, e.g. `<div>hello</div>`, so for a server, returning an html file is no different than returning a text file. The server is actually returning the contents of the file--and the contents have no extension.  You need to understand that it's all just text that gets sent "over the wire".

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a tcp server that listens on some port, and returns some html when a request comes in.
2. In a browser's address bar, specify the address where the server is listening(e.g. `localhost`, which is the address 127.0.0.1, which is an address on your computer) along with the port where the server is listening, e.g. `http://localhost:3456`.

There's one big hitch: there is no universal protocol for servers and clients (e.g browsers) to communicate with each other.  The issue is caused by the way text is sent to a tcp socket.  When you send some text to a tcp socket, you have no idea whether the text will get broken up into chunks, nor how long each chunk will be.  The data may get sent as one chunk, or the data may get chopped into ten chunks.  That presents a problem for the receiver of the data: how does the receiver know when it should stop trying to read data from the socket because no more data is coming?

To solve that problem, both the client and the server have to agree on a ***protocol***, which is an agreed upon format for the data, so that the other side can easily parse the data, as well as an agreed upon signal that the end of the data has been reached, so that the other side can stop trying to read data from the socket.  The easiest protocol is for the sender to close their socket when they are done sending data.  The receiver will then attempt to keep reading data from the socket until it gets a socket error, then it knows no more data is coming.

Or, the protocol could be when the word "end" is encountered in the data--then the receiver should stop trying to read from the socket when it reads "end".  But, here is an example of how that can cause problems:

```
msg = "I finished the end of the book.  It was great!"
to_send = msg <> "end"
```

The receiver will think it has come to the end of the message once it reads "I finished the end", which is only part of the message.  An end marker like `**&&=>END1234<=!!**` would work better.  Similarly, the protocol to mark the end of the data could be a newline("\n").  For instance, the listen socket option `packet: :line` sets things up so that `:get_tcp.recv()` will read one line from the socket.

Yet another protocol is to use the first 4 bytes of the data to specify an integer that is the number of bytes that the other side should subsequently read from the socket.  The receiver waits until it has read 4 bytes from the socket, then the receiver reads an additional N bytes(the integer contained in the first 4 bytes), and once N more bytes are read the receiver knows that's the end of the data.

The protocol that web browsers and servers have agreed upon is the `http request` and `http response` protocol.  You can see some examples of the http request and response format [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages).  Because you are coding the tcp server, you can simplify things by ignoring the request completely (so you don't care about the format) and return the same response for any request that comes in.  Also, doing that obviates the need to figure out when the server should stop trying to read from the socket.

The response your tcp server sends back does have to obey the http response protocol because you will need a browser to receive the response in order to see the rendered html, i.e. you want to type `http://localhost:33444` in your browser's address bar.

Below is an example of the  echo server modified so that it adheres to the http response protocol and also returns some html in the body of the response:

```
~/elixir_programs/tcp_server$ tree .
.
├── page.html
├── resp_header.txt
└── s1.ex
```

**s1.ex**:

```
defmodule HtmlServer do
  require Logger

  def accept(port) do
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(
        port,
        [:binary, 
         packet: :line, 
         active: false, 
         reuseaddr: true]
    )
    Logger.info "Accepting connections on port #{port}"
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp loop_acceptor(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    Task.start_link(fn -> serve(client) end)
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp serve(socket) do
    line = read_socket(socket)  #blocks until something is read from the socket
    IO.puts "[ME] Got some data! #{line}"

    resp_header = File.read! "./resp_header.txt"
    resp_body = File.read! "./page.html" 
    content_len = String.length(resp_body)

    resp = 
        resp_header <> 
        "Content-Length: #{content_len}\n" <>
        "\n" <>
        resp_body

    #IO.inspect resp

    write_socket(resp, socket)
    :ok = :gen_tcp.close(socket)
  end

  defp read_socket(socket) do
    {:ok, data} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
    data
  end

  defp write_socket(data, socket) do
    :gen_tcp.send(socket, data)
  end

  def start() do
    accept(9999)
  end
end
```

**resp_header.txt**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

**page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <style>
      .greeting {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="greeting">Hello World</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs/tcp_server$ iex s1.ex 
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> HtmlServer.start

10:08:34.016 [info]  Accepting connections on port 9999
```

Then open a browser window and paste the following adddress into your browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost:9999
```

Comment: Is there a way I can just put a get{ /HTML block} or something like that to get like continuous HTML files if I have those HTML files? Would it run like that?

Comment: @KKNg,  You are writing the server from scratch, and the only thing that is implemented in the `:gen_tcp` module are the functions for creating sockets, connecting client and server sockets, reading from a socket and sending data to the socket, and closing sockets.  Browsers can handle continuous streaming of data to a socket (see the Keep-Alive header) but there is a protocol that has to be followed, so your server would have to implement that protocol.  However, instead of trying to implement that yourself, I would look at phoenix-framework.  After all, it's why we all learn elixir isn't it?

Comment: You should also realize by looking at the code, that there is no router: all requests return the same thing.  So, if you want to respond to different paths in the request url with different html pages, then you have to implement a router.  How would you do that?  The first line of an http request is:  `"GET /hello.htm HTTP/1.1"`.  So you would need to split that string on whitespace and retrieve the path.